# how to make two lists not share their values in python3

Tags: python-3.x

After running this code below,

```
a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
b = a
c = a
t = 'A'

b[0] = t + c[0]
```

b is `['Ax', 'y', 'z']` and c is also `['Ax', 'y', 'z']`

How can I make two lists not share their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy of a, otherwise you are just saying that b points to the same object as a, and same for c. You can do this two ways

```
b=a.copy
c=list(a)
```

EDIT: A bit more detail for you. When you use the equals sign to assign a variable to an object in python it's just like sticking a post-it note to that object with the variable name. You created a list object and stuck the name 'a' to it. You then stuck the name 'b' and 'c' to the same object. In this case there is fundamentally only one list object, it just has three names. The `copy` method creates a second object the same as a the first. The `list` function returns a new list. If you give it a list as input it's essentially just another way of doing a copy.

It's worth noting that if the list contains other objects (e.g. a list of lists) then these will not be copied. For that you should use `deepcopy`.